# create symboliclink with powershell

Tags: powershell

I write script below to compare and create symboliclink with powershell.

```
$Source = "C:\Transcode\Powershell\abc&1"
$Destination = "C:\Transcode\Powershell\abc&2"
$filter = '*.txt'
$tmp = "$Source\tmp.log"
$log =   "$Source\delete.log"

function New-SymLink ($link, $target)
{
    if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 5)
    {
        New-Item -Path $link -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value $target
    }
    else
    {
        $command = "cmd /c mklink "
        invoke-expression "$command ""$link"" ""$target"""
    }
}
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter $filter -Recurse | 
ForEach-Object {
    $name=$_.BaseName
    $ext=$_.Extension
    $fileS=$_.FullName
    $fileD="$Destination\$name$ext"
    IF (Get-Content $tmp | Where-Object{$_ -match "$name"}){
        New-SymLink ("""""$fileD""""","""""$fileS""""")
    }
}
```

I get trouble with file name what contains symbol `&`.
I can create link by call command promt like this

```
cmd /c mklink """$Destination\$name$ext""" """$fileS"""
```

But I want to use function.
Can you help me resovle it

Comment: You should use single quotes (‘’) around strings that you want to pass literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (only partly tested) streamlined version which

- escapes the `&` in `$command` with a caret `^&`
- removes redundancy and possibly unneeded quoting

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\23\SO_55803869.ps1
$Source      = "C:\Transcode\Powershell\abc&1"
$Destination = "C:\Transcode\Powershell\abc&2"
$filter      = '*.txt'
$tmp         = Get-Content "$Source\tmp.log"
$log         = "$Source\delete.log"

function New-SymLink ($link, $target){
    if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 5){
        New-Item -Path $link -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value $target
    } else {
        $command = 'cmd.exe /c mklink "{0}" "{1}"' -f $link,$target
        invoke-expression $command.Replace('&','^&')
    }
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter $filter -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $fileD= Join-Path $Destination $_.Name
    IF ($tmp | Where-Object {$_ -match $_.BaseName} ) {
        New-SymLink $fileD $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for optimizing my script. But, the script successfully ran with the file name '123&abc', not successfully with file name 'New Text Document'

Comment: I have 1 questions. If I comment line `invoke-expression $command.Replace('&','^&')`, why function doesn't run.

Comment: I edit line `invoke-expression $command.Replace('&','^&')` into `invoke-expression $command.Replace('&','&')`. Script runs as well except file name `123&abc`. 
I think the problem in the string has only letters and 2 "&" symbol. Example: `cmd.exe /c mklink "C:\Transcode\Powershell\abc&2\123&abc.txt" "C:\Transcode\Powershell\abc&1\123&abc.txt"'